# Sitefinity fails to initialize with error: The type initializer for 'Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.SecurityManager' threw an exception

Tags: asp.net, telerik, sitefinity

As the title reads, I'm trying to run a Sitefinity project with Visual Studio 2015.

On initialization, the little gear icons break and I'm presented with this woefully vague error message:

`The type initializer for 'Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.SecurityManager' threw an exception.`

My machine seems to be the only one experiencing this. My google-fu has thus far failed me. I've given full access to all users on my system to no avail. I'm tearing my hair out here.

Comment: Can you please attach your detailed message from error logs. You can find it here /App_Data/Sitefinity/Logs

Comment: There's nothing there :/ it seems to not be logging anything.

Comment: Exactly the same source code and DB are working fine in other machine?

Comment: Yep, pulled the code fresh from source control and restored the DB from a backup.

Comment: Do you have Windows 10 Creators update? It might happpens because .net framework 4.7. Please check this article http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/local-site-suddenly-stopped-working-after-running-the-windows-10-updates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue happened because of Windows 10 creators update (.Net Framework 4.7).
Progress released hotfix for Sitefinity versions on May 29th, 2017:

- 10
- 9.2, 9.1, 9.0
- 8.2, 8.1, 8.0
- 7.3, 7.2, 7.1, 7.0

You can check version notes here: http://www.sitefinity.com/product/version-notes

You need to update your version of Sitefinity, which contains this hotfix. Or you need to roll back your windows update (.Net Framework 4.7)

Article: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/local-site-suddenly-stopped-working-after-running-the-windows-10-updates

Comment: Thanks, Victor. Glad I'm not insane.

Comment: Thanks victor. We had to roll back update because of this and I was trying to find if its really issue with update or there's something else.