# Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.SecurityManager exception after upgrade to .NET Framework 4.7

Tags: asp.net, exception, dll, sitefinity

I was trying to run a project when it started a Telerik.Sitefinity Exception (Can see better the attached files) and after some research it seems the reason was because of an upgrade of the .NET Framework to 4.7.

I saw page in the link http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/sitefinity-and-net-4-7-compatibility-issues  and verified that the problem maybe could be solved by using an internal build or hotfix. I verified that the SiteFinity version is 8.2 and for that reason I decided to use the Sitefinity Internal Build 8.2.5941.0.

Ialso saw the link http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/How-to-update-Sitefinity-to-hotfix-internal-build-or-a-patch and installed the Telerik.Sitefinity.All NuGet package and tried to follow the import steps of the option 2 but I don't what what they mean with "Note the exact build number of the hotfix or internal build".

Then I tried the approach in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241613.aspx and it seems that the internal builds pdbs are being used.

Then I the the solution build and run the project but without success because it happened the same exception.

Can anyone please tell me what could be happening? Solutions?

Thanks for any help!

Images:

http://www.sitefinity.com/clientsfiles/5c5a561e-37c1-6deb-a958-ff0000446526_dlls-and-pdbs.png?sfvrsn=949b3bd3_0

http://www.sitefinity.com/clientsfiles/675a561e-37c1-6deb-a958-ff0000446526_net-framework-upgrade.png?sfvrsn=af9b3bd3_0

http://www.sitefinity.com/clientsfiles/a45a561e-37c1-6deb-a958-ff0000446526_telerik-sitefinity-exception.png?sfvrsn=6c9b3bd3_0

Comment: Did you actually upgrade to the latest hotfix? The first screenshot says the installed version of Sitefinity.All is 8.2.5907. You have to upgrade it to 8.2.5941.0 - you can use the Updates tab in Nuget. Then rebuild the solution and see if error is gone.

Comment: Yes, I tried by importing the PDB's files and by using the project manager and it didn't work.

Comment: hm, not sure what importing pdb files has to do with this. leave pdb files alone for now, they are not needed. Can you confirm you are running the upgraded .5941 version?

Comment: PDBs do not matter for this. You need the patched DLLs.

Comment: This has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44260231/825011

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the internal build was not installed. Try running the following command in the Package Manager Console and building the project after that:

Install-Package Telerik.Sitefinity.All -Version 8.2.5941.0 -Source http://nuget.sitefinity.com/nuge

In the above statement 8.2.5941.0 is the exact build number the KB article is referring to. In this case, it comes from the KB article stating in which version the problem with .NET 4.7 is resolved. The issue is not actually related to the OS.

The .dll files are what determines the running version of Sitefinity and not the .pdb files. The version of the dll can be checked by righ-clicking on it, going to Properties and examining the Details tab. Check that for the Telerik.Sitefinity.dll file.

The .pdb files provide extended error logging capabilities (among other things) in cases where that is needed but should not be kept in the bin folder at all times due to performance concerns. They would only have effect if they are the same version as the dll files.

In regards to hotfix2 it should be listed under your account as 8.2.5940. Here's some more information where to find it: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Where-to-find-the-hot-fix--internal-builds-for-download

Answer (score 1):

I have WIndows 8.1 and not 10. But anyway, I followed the instructions on the link that you mentioned before and on the site finity I did go to "Overview -> Products & Subscriptions -> Sitefinity CMS -> Download Installer and other resources -> Latest Internal Builds." as mentioned in the link:

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Where-to-find-the-hot-fix--internal-builds-for-download?q=Local+site+suddenly+stopped+working+after+running+the+Windows+10+Updates&c=Product_Group%3ASitefinity&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1

But the problem is that I only find the internal build which I already used it but didn't solve the problem as I mentioned in my posts above. I can't find the "Sitefinity 8.2 Hotfix2".

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue documented here. Could you follow the instruction to update sitefinity hotfix?

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/local-site-suddenly-stopped-working-after-running-the-windows-10-updates?q=Local+site+suddenly+stopped+working+after+running+the+Windows+10+Updates&l=en_US&c=Product_Group%3ASitefinity&fs=Search&pn=1

Answer (score 0):

For me the only solution was to format my PC and use Windows 7. This OS don't have the .Net Framework 4.7.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but I would like to show a workaround for users who cannot install the hotfix.

Go to the web.config and comment out the following -

```
<membership defaultProvider="Default">
  <!-- <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="Default" type="Telerik.Sitefinity.Security.Data.SitefinityMembershipProvider, Telerik.Sitefinity" />
  </providers> -->
</membership>
```

Comment: @VeselinVasilev yes :)